# How to insert into db in spring-data?

Tags: spring, spring-data

I want to make a request that inserts data into my database. The table has 4 columns: ID_DOCUMENT (PK), ID_TASK, DESCRIPTION, FILEPATH

**Entity**

```
... 
@Column(name = "ID_TASK")
private Long idTask;


@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name = "FILEPATH")
private String filepath;
...
```

**Repository**

```
@Modifying
@Query("insert into TaskDocumentEntity c (c.idTask, c.description, c.filepath) values (:id,:description,:filepath)")
public void insertDocumentByTaskId(@Param("id") Long id,@Param("description") String description,@Param("filepath") String filepath);
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/services/tasks/addDocument", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void set(@RequestParam("idTask") Long idTask,@RequestParam("description") String description,@RequestParam("filepath") String filepath){

    //TaskDocumentEntity document = new TaskDocumentEntity();
    taskDocumentRepository.insertDocumentByTaskId(idTask,descriere,filepath);
}
```

When I run my test, I get this error:
 *Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found 'c' near line 1, column 32 [insert into TaskDocumentEntity c   (c.idTask, c.descriere, c.filepath) values (:id,:descriere,:filepath)]*
    I tried to remove the alias c, and still doesn`t work.

Comment: Remove your `insertDocumentByTaskId`. In your controller create an instance of `TaskDocumentEntity` set the properties and call the `save` method. The whole point of JPA is that you don't have to write your queries anymore...

Comment: Please post the code for your repository class not only the method declaration and also post your spring configuration class/xml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring data provides out of the box `save` method used for insertion to database - no need to use `@Query`. Take a look at core concepts of springData (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

thus in your controller just create object `TaskDocumentEntity` and pass it to repository

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/services/tasks/addDocument", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void set(@RequestParam("idTask") Long idTask,@RequestParam("description") String description,@RequestParam("filepath") String filepath){

// assign parameters to taskDocumentEntity by constructor args or setters
        TaskDocumentEntity document = new TaskDocumentEntity(idTask,descriere,filepath);
        taskDocumentRepository.save(document);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this also, but doesn`t persist, no changes the database (succesful test)

Comment: It works now, I didn`t inject the service in the test class, and didn`t pass any params for the request, anyway I `ve rewritten the controller, thanks a lot guys !!!

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this but it depends on the db you're using.  Below worked for me in Oracle (using Dual table):

```
@Repository
public interface DualRepository extends JpaRepository<Dual,Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("insert into Person (id,name,age) select :id,:name,:age from Dual")
    public int modifyingQueryInsertPerson(@Param("id")Long id, @Param("name")String name, @Param("age")Integer age);
}
```

So in your case, it would be (if Oracle):

```
@Modifying
@Query("insert into TaskDocumentEntity (idTask,description,filepath) select :idTask,:description,:filepath from Dual")
public void insertDocumentByTaskId(@Param("idTask") Long id,@Param("description") String description,@Param("filepath") String filepath)
```

I'm not sure which db you're using, here's a link which shows at the bottom which db's support select stmts without a from clause : http://modern-sql.com/use-case/select-without-from